# PHP GD drawing in foreach loop

Tags: php, gd

I have the following code that draws green squares on an image using GD:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("images/dota.png");
$radiantcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 7, 251, 15);
$direcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 250, 2, 0);

$x = array(
0 => 38,
1 => 45,
2 => 25,
3 => 29,
4 => 34,
5 => 62,
6 => 83,
7 => 116,
8 => 76,
9 => 135,
10 => 232,
);

$y = array(
0 => 234,
1 => 240,
2 => 205,
3 => 161,
4 => 116,
5 => 219,
6 => 198,
7 => 171,
8 => 256,
9 => 260,
10 => 257,
);

foreach ($towerstatus_radiant as $key => $tower){
if ($tower == 1){
    $x = $x[$key];
    $y = $y[$key];
    imagefilledrectangle($img, $x, $y, $x+8, $y+8, $radiantcolor);
}
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
```

It works just fine with the first square, but after that, the squares just seems to be placed in the top left corner, like this:

[image]

Why could this be?

Comment: `$towerstatus_radiant` is not defined in your code, so nobody should be able to tell you and could only guess. You should prevent guessing when debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your $x and $y variables here:

```
$x = $x[$key];
$y = $y[$key];
```

You need to use different variable names here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Totally missed that.